# How to get index of sublist from original list

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I have a list `A = [[1,3],[0,1,2],[0,2,4]]` and sublist of A which is tuple `B = ([1, 3], [0, 2, 4])`. I want to print length of `B` and index of each element of `B` in original List `A`. I am not sure how to return the indexes.

The output should be:

```
2
0 2
```

Here is my try:

```
A = [[1,3],[0,1,2],[0,2,4]]
B = ([1, 3], [0, 2, 4])
print(len(B),'\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
In [81]: A
Out[81]: [[1, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4]]

In [82]: B
Out[82]: ([1, 3], [0, 2, 4])

In [83]: print(len(B))
    ...: for item in B:
    ...:     print(A.index(list(item)), end=' ')
    ...:
```

**Output**

```
2  
0 2
```

Based on your comment:

```
print(str(len(B)) + '\n' + ' '.join([str(A.index(item)) for item in B]))
```

**Output:**

```
2
0 2
```

Comment: Thanks. Since its sniped code from original code, I am looking for a way to print it with one print command.

Comment: `print(str(len(B)) + '\n' + ' '.join([str(A.index(item)) for item in B]))`

Answer (score 0):

This will work you

```
print(len(b), tuple(map(lambda b: A.index(b), B)))
```